# Pass a variable from flask/python to HTML, and back

Tags: python, html, variables, flask

I have a flask template where I see a list of all switches of a certain zone. 
I would like to have this list to be all links that will open a new tab showing the content of a textfile, locally stored.

It works fine if I'm defining the correct file, but if I use the variable used to show the files in the directory it does not work. I know the issue lies with the notation of the url_for tag in HTML, but what is the correct notation?

The HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 main">
  <h1 class="page-header">Actual switch configs of BE</h1>
    <ol> 
      {%for i in range(0, len)%} 
        <ul>
          <a href="{{url_for('switch', switch={{files[i]}}  )}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> {{files[i]}}</a>
        </ul> 
      {%endfor%} 
    </ol> 
</div>
```

```py
@app.route('/switch/', defaults={'switch':None})
@app.route('/switch/<switch>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def switch(switch):
    return render_template('/configs/'+directory+'/'+switch+'.txt', len = len(files), files=files, name = current_user.username)
```

The error I got is:

```
    jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /configs/BE_actual/{{files[i]}}.txt
```

Which makes sense to me, but I fail to write it correctly.
I tried with {{files[i]|safe}} but the issue remains.

Comment: use `files[i]` without `{{ }}`- `url_for` and `files[i]` are both code which can run in the same `{{ }}` - `{{url_for('switch', switch=files[i])}}`. OR even use `{%for item in files %}  {{url_for('switch', switch=item)}}` and you will no need `len`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url_for` and `files[i]` are both code so they can run in the same `{{ }}`

```
"{{ url_for('switch', switch=files[i]) }}"
```

---

You can also use

```
 {%for item in files %} 

  "{{ url_for('switch', switch=item) }}"
```

and you will no need `len`